# R Create SQL Table from Data Frame

Tags: sql, r, t-sql

In R, is there a straightforward way to load the entire contents of a data frame into a new SQL Server database table?

In my situation, I already have a connection to the SQL Server database and the ability to query, etc.

Comment: Please try to figure out the problem yourself and if you still don't get it post what you tried.

Comment: This should be helpful: https://blog.rstudio.com/2017/06/27/dbplyr-1-1-0/.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a better question for another forum because the question seems to be about methodology and choosing packages vs a coding example that is not working.  Depending on your connection and where the database is, the answers might vary wildly.